# How reliable are aircraft cutaway drawings from Flightglobal?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing, aircraft-maintenance, airframe, stc

I am working on a new system that would be retrofitted on jets (can't talk much about it yet), and I was looking for detailed drawings to start creating its detailed engineering design.

I stumbled upon [this website](http://www.flightglobalimages.com/bombardier-challenger-605-cutaway-poster/print/1865491.html), does any of you know how reliable Flightglobal and those drawings are / where they get their information? Your opinion would help a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: How critical is the system? Have you planned how to certify it with not knowing exact engineering detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These cutaways are just general representations of what structural components go into the aircraft; they are NOT engineering drawings nor should they be used as such.

In general the OEMs and the engineering departments for the airlines are pretty sensitive about releasing engineering data for proprietary reasons.  If you are working on a product closely with an OEM or an airline, they may be able to grant you a license to access such data, generally for a substantial fee. Or, if you have a client who will allow you access to the aircraft, you may be able to take engineering photos and/or make detailed measurements directly on the aircraft.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I expected but I still had a bit of hope... I'm also currently working on option 2 (access the aircraft and reverse-engineer the drawings) because, as you mentioned, OEMs are really sensitive about sharing this kind of information.